# Affiliations with multiple lines of information

Tags: line-breaking, titles, authblk, affiliation

I want to format affiliations for a paper in a certain way - so that is looks like the following

[image]

I have tried the following code

```
\title{TITLE}
\author[1]{Author1}
\affil[1]{School \\ University \\ Email: author1@university.com}
\author[2]{Author 2}
\affil[2]{School \\ University \\ Email: author2@university.com}
```

and also

```
\title{TITLE}
\author{Author1}
\affil{School \\ University 
\\ Email: author1@university.com}

\author{Author 2}
\affil{School \\ University
\\ Email: author2@university.com}
```

But both produce results which are subtly wrong. Any suggestions?

Here is the code used to produce what I have so far:

Yes I am using authblk.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{TITLE}
\author[1]{Author1}
\affil[1]{School \\ University 
 \\ Email: author1@university.com}

 \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\protect` the line breaks:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{TITLE}
\author[1]{Author1}
\affil[1]{School \protect\\ University \protect\\ Email: author1@university.com}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

The package provides the command `\authorcr` for breaking lines.  The documentation says this is for use within `\author`, but it also works in the `\affil`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{TITLE}
\author[1]{Author1}
\affil[1]{School, University \authorcr
  Email: author1@university.com}
\author[2]{Author2}
\affil[2]{School, University \authorcr
  Email: author1@university.com} 

 \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd like to add that this solution does not really work if one has redefined `\Authfont` and `\Afillfont` – the line after the line break uses \Authfont. Thus, perhaps using `\protect` is a more stable solution.

Comment: @Indeed the `\authorcr` command contains a switch back to the `\Authfont`.  One can define `\newcommand\affilcr{\protect\\ \protect\Affilfont}` and use that, but that is what is essentially in Werner's answer anyway.